# Where to log events before setting up logging in python?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I need to know where the should I log events before setting up the `logging` module.

I have an application that reads a yaml file during startup. The file contains path where the application and error logs should be stored. Where can I log events like exceptions should I encounter one while before the application can get to the point of setting up `logging` module? Thank you

Comment: Python logging is very flexible. Set up logging with some default parameters, load the file, add another logging handler, copy logged data, delete/replace default handler.